# Using T4MVC when Controllers and Views are in different Libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, t4mvc

Is it possible to use T4MVC when The Controllers and Models are in a different Library to the Views?

> For example,
>
> - Namespace.Common.MVC
>
> which contains the **Controllers** and **Models**, which is referenced
>   by
>
> - Namespace.MvcApplication1
> - Namespace.MvcApplication2
>
> which contains the **Views**.

Installing the nuget T4MVC package into `Common.MVC` and `MvcApplication1` works fine, but when trying to use `MVC.` on a View there is an error that `MVC` exists in multiple namespaces, which is logical.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just like any C# code, if you are trying to use a type whose name exists in multiple namespaces you will need to provide some help to the compiler so that it can figure out which of the types you are referring to.

The options in this case are:

- Fully qualify the MVC type name e.g. in your views use `Namespace.Common.MVC.MVC`
- Change the name of the generated type in each of the projects. E.g. open the `T4MVC.tt.settings.xml` file in your common project and change the value of the `<HelpersPrefix>` element from `MVC` to something unique such as `MVCCommon`. In your views you can now reference it as `MVCCommon.Something`